# RMarkdown wrap long text with underline in kable to PDF

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I would like wrap long text in my kable table while also keep the text underlined. Output is PDF. Here is a simple example of a table with column text that is too long and needs to be wrapped for the table to fit on the page. Example based on [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf).

```
# Load packages
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
dt <- tibble(
Items = c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"),
Text_1 = c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula tempor ex. Morbi m
Text_2 = c("Duis posuere placerat magna, ac aliquam lorem viverra non. Ut ultrices tempus eros, quis s
)

# Wrapping works
kbl(dt, "latex", booktabs = T,
col.names = c("Item", "Short Title", "Very Very Very Very Very Very Long Title")) %>%
column_spec(2:3, width = "5cm")
```

Wrapping stops working as soon as I add an underline to the last column:

```
# Table with underline
kbl(dt, "latex", booktabs = T, escape = F,
    col.names = c("Item", "Short Title", "Very Very Very Very Very Very Long Title")) |> 
  column_spec(2:3, width = "5cm") |> 
  column_spec(3, underline = TRUE, color = "blue")
```

Is there a way to keep both underline and linebreaks in PDF-output?